# Why does my ASCII ART in LC-3 look so ugly?

Tags: assembly, lc3, ascii-art

I have written an LC-3 program that outputs some ASCII ART. It spells the word "COOL". But the picture turns out to be very ugly.
This is what I get:

[image]

and this is what I would like to see:

> ```
>    _____ ____   ____  _      
>   / ____/ __ \ / __ \| |     
>  | |   | |  | | |  | | |     
>  | |   | |  | | |  | | |     
>  | |___| |__| | |__| | |____ 
>   \_____\____/ \____/|______|
> ```

My program:

```
.ORIG x3000
ADD R0, R0, #0
LEA R0, ART
LOOP TRAP x22;
ADD R1, R1, #-1;
BRp LOOP;

ART .stringz "\n   _____ ____   ____  _      \n  / ____/ __ \ / __ \| |     \n | |   | |  | | |  | | |     \n | |   | |  | | |  | | |     \n | |___| |__| | |__| | |____ \n  \_____\____/ \____/|______|\n                             \n                             \n"
COUNTER .fill #1;
.END
```

I have tried to fix my code by adding spaces, but it still doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: This happens because the backslash "\" is used as an escape character! You use it already for the newlines "\n", but your logo design contains 5 additional backslashes that you want to display on screen. You need to double them like in "\\".

Comment: @SepRoland: This is reopened now, if you wanted to post that as an answer now that you've fixed the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was my idea.

Comment: @SepRoland: I had a look for duplicates of backslash in `.ascii` or `.string` but didn't find any.  Only a few things that seemed to be about inline asm where the asm itself has to be in a C string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The picture gets distorted because the backslash character "\" is used as an escape character! You use it already for the newlines "\n", but your logo design contains 5 additional backslashes that you want to display on screen. You need to double them like in "\\".

You can read about the escape characters in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Below is the new string definition where I have doubled the five backslashes:

```
ART .stringz "\n   _____ ____   ____  _      \n  / ____/ __ \\ / __ \\| |     \n | |   | |  | | |  | | |     \n | |   | |  | | |  | | |     \n | |___| |__| | |__| | |____ \n  \\_____\\____/ \\____/|______|\n                             \n                             \n"
```